# Удалил apache, но внешний сайт не вижу на ubuntu

Tags: apache, ubuntu

Удалил apache. Я думал, что теперь удалиться локальный сайт и я буду видеть по тойже ссылке внешний сайт, но внешний сайт не вижу... Теперь выдаёт лишь это сообщение "К сожалению, Google Chrome не может открыть страницу..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удали строку с адресом сайта из /etc/hosts